# Error when trying to run a development theme with Shopify CLI Command

Tags: command-line-interface, shopify

I am trying to run a development theme with Shopify CLI Command.

The theme I am using is Palo Alto and it's unpublished (for the moment). When I run "Shopify theme Serve" , some files wont load and I am getting error message :

11:26:44 ERROR » update sections/header.liquid:┃ New schema is incompatible with the current setting value. Setting 'logo_max_width' must be a step in the range.New schema is incompatible with the current setting value. Invalid value for type in block 'edb24fec-6e96-4fc2-a2d3-7a4ba77d34c7'. Type must be defined in schema..New schema is incompatible with the current setting value. Invalid value for type in block 'footer-1'. Type must be defined in schema..New schema is incompatible with the current setting value. Invalid value for type in block '2387d8a4-2816-4cce-9561-456f922137f7'. Type must be defined in schema.

Any idea where this is coming from and how to fix it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your theme files you have a file called `settings_data.json` and a file called `settings_schema.json`.

The schema defines what possible option you may have, (for example, "Banner Image", "Font Size", etc) for each page.

The data defines the value of those options (a certain image, a certain font size).

The error is saying "You're trying to publish a theme with incoherent data and schema". In particular it seems that `logo_max_width` has a value not in the range of the schema.

My suggestion is to search for `logo_max_width` inside `settings_data.json` check the values (there could be more than one, but given the error should be in a block with id `edb24fec-6e96-4fc2-a2d3-7a4ba77d34c7`), then search for it inside the schema and check whether the value is within the range there specified.

Whenever the value inside data is out of range put a value that is within the range.

Regarding `footer-1` it seems that that value is not defined in the schema, so you can remove it everywhere inside `settings_data.json`.

NB. Sometimes the schema can be specified inside a section page html. So if you don't find `logo_max_width` inside the schema file check in the sections folder.